# Cannot convert Char to money

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

getting this error when trying to convert a column to money value
Msg 235, Level 16, State 0, Line 10
Cannot convert a char value to money. The char value has incorrect syntax.

```
 CONVERT(MONEY, LEFT(SubSTRING(l.LineIDNumber, PATINDEX('%[0-9.-]%', l.LineIDNumber), 10),
           PATINDEX('%[^0-9.-]%', SUBSTRING(l.LineIDNumber, PATINDEX('%[0-9.-]%', l.LineIDNumber), 10) + 'X') -1)) as PriorPremium,
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is product specific.)

Comment: I am using Sql server 2012

Comment: Test the value you're building to be sure it's a number - `where isnumeric(left(substring....) = 0` Or I think you can use try_convert the same way.

Comment: What is the string value? You *don't* need string manipulations to convert a valid numeric string to a numeric type - and money is *not* a good choice anyway. You can use `cast`, convert with a style number or [PARSE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parse-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) with a culture identifier

Comment: What would really help is some sample data and desired output. [mcve]

Comment: Do a select without the conversion to money and inspect the results for things that will not convert.  `select LEFT(SubSTRING(l.LineIDNumber, PATINDEX('%[0-9.-]%', l.LineIDNumber), 10),
           PATINDEX('%[^0-9.-]%', SUBSTRING(l.LineIDNumber, PATINDEX('%[0-9.-]%', l.LineIDNumber), 10) + 'X') -1) as PriorPremium`

Comment: For example you can use `PARSE('3.4' as money using 'en-US')` or `PARSE('3,4' as money using 'fr-FR')` to parse strings with different separators

Comment: On the other hand I wouldn't expect a field named `LineIDNumber` to contain money amounts. What does this field contain? Why is `X` appended to some other string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without having a sample of your data this is purely speculation.

It would appear you have a field in the dataset that you are trying to convert that has 2 or more periods.

```
declare @test char(12) = '3445.76'

select CONVERT(MONEY, LEFT(SubSTRING(@test, PATINDEX('%[0-9.-]%', @test), 10),
           PATINDEX('%[^0-9.-]%', SUBSTRING(@test, PATINDEX('%[0-9.-]%', @test), 10) + 'X') -1)) as PriorPremium
```

The above returns a value of 3445.76

```
declare @test char(12) = '34a5.76'

select CONVERT(MONEY, LEFT(SubSTRING(@test, PATINDEX('%[0-9.-]%', @test), 10),
           PATINDEX('%[^0-9.-]%', SUBSTRING(@test, PATINDEX('%[0-9.-]%', @test), 10) + 'X') -1)) as PriorPremium
```

The above returns 34.00

```
declare @test char(12) = '34.45.76'

select CONVERT(MONEY, LEFT(SubSTRING(@test, PATINDEX('%[0-9.-]%', @test), 10),
           PATINDEX('%[^0-9.-]%', SUBSTRING(@test, PATINDEX('%[0-9.-]%', @test), 10) + 'X') -1)) as PriorPremium
```

Returns the error you specified

> Msg 235, Level 16, State 0, Line 3 Cannot convert a char value to
>   money. The char value has incorrect syntax.

You need to clean up your data before you can convert it.